# Toolbar is not responding to anything

Tags: java, android, xml, toolbar

I am stuck on a very interesting problem that I have tried to solve for quite some time.
I have added toolbars to views in Android before, but have never faced the below problem.

When accessing the Toolbar directly, or assigning it by `setSupportActionBar(myToolbar)` The toolbar itself will not be modifiable in any way. I even tried setting the view to gone, and it would not work. As well, the toolbar has nothing on it. No app name, no hamburger menu or back arrow, nothing.

Relevant code posted below:

**BaseActivity.java**

```
@Nullable
@BindView(R.id.app_bar)
protected Toolbar mToolbar;

private Unbinder unbinder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getLayoutResource());
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this);

    if(mToolbar != null) {
        Timber.tag("Toolbar").d("Toolbar is not null. Oh glorious day");
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    }
}
```

**base_drawer_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/container_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="true">

            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorDefaultBackground</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

The application tag in my manifest also has `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` set

The toolbar itself is not null in the view (have already checked that)
And it is not the SDK itself, as I opened up a project using the same method of creating a support action bar and it worked fine.

Am I missing something really obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

After looking around a bit, I found that my child class was actually calling setContent, as well as my parent class, overriding any changes to the view I had made.

Just a simple oversight on my part.